# how can i keep the element visible when linking to it with a top navbar

Tags: html, css, navigation

i am using bootstrap here and i was trying to make a nav bar with some content and there is a link to a part of the site but the text i am linking to  is being covered by the top nav bar

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <title>website with navbar</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container sticky-top" style="background-color: #f1f1f1; top: 0;">
    <h1>website</h1>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <il class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">first lecture</a></il>
      <il class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link"><b>second lecture</b></a></il>
      <il class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">third lecture</a></il>
      <il class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">fourth lecture</a></il>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    <a href="https://shiyarjemo.com">موقع coder shiyar</a><br>
    <a href="mailto:abas93931@gmail.com" target="_blank">email</a><br>
    <a href="tel:9647731150337">telephone</a>
    <a href=""></a>
    <h1 style="height: 700px; background-color: red;" id="h11">
      <a href="#h1">first part</a>
    </h1>
    <h1 style="height: 700px;background-color: rgb(0, 255, 42);" id="h1">
      <a href="#h11">second part</a>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.9.2/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can u provide screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to the style of the first `<div>` with class of `.container` (The one on top of `<h1>website</h1>`),

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <title>website with navbar</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container sticky-top" style="background-color: #f1f1f1; top: 0; position: relative;">
        <h1>website</h1>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <il class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">first lecture</a></il>
            <il class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link"><b>second lecture</b></a></il>
            <il class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">third lecture</a></il>
            <il class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">fourth lecture</a></il>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 30px;">
        <a href="https://shiyarjemo.com">موقع coder shiyar</a><br>
        <a href="mailto:abas93931@gmail.com" target="_blank">email</a><br>
        <a href="tel:9647731150337">telephone</a>
        <a href=""></a>
        <h1 style="height: 700px; background-color: red;" id="h11">
            <a href="#h1">first part</a>
        </h1>
        <h1 style="height: 700px;background-color: rgb(0, 255, 42);" id="h1">
            <a href="#h11">second part</a>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.9.2/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```